# Slowness after converting TFS projects to Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

After converting a big TFS project to Git(using Git TF), I'm having slowness problems with operations like View History, pull, push, sync, etc. being done from Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git gc --auto` for the troubled repository solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here!